# Question regarding waves squeezed

Tags: waves, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

in one MOOC I am taking, the professor had a slide stating "when squeezed into a narrow space wave is amplified". I am not sure I understand what he meant by that, and I am trying to think into terms of wave equations. Could anyone explain it to me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give more context? What types of waves? How were they being squeezed?

Comment: He was referring to the uncertainty principle in the inflation of the universe, and he gave as an example the tsunami, which hit a confined bay area (So the height of the crest would increase, I am assuming).